# Quasar Q-Table how can I get the filtered or sorted rows?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, quasar

I am get stucked ,I installed Quasar version 2.0.0 but it does not has a property to get the filtered or sorted rows.In previous versions of q-table it had a computedRows property but in the latest version it didn't
I am trying to add new features to the q-table like highlight focused row and enable keyboard features to allow in-line editing etc... so I need to know the row data(model) and its corresponding html row.

- Quasar ver:2.0.0
- Vuejs 3
- Typescript

Comment: I just start with Quasar but I have this.$refs.myTable.computedRows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a temporary solution:
here is my q-table :

```
 <template v-slot:body="props">
     <q-tr
         class="row-data"
          :props="props"
          :rowID="props.row.id"
        >
 <q-td
            @click="onTdClick($event, props.row, 
                   props.rowIndex, index)"
            v-for="(col, index) in props.cols"
            :key="col.name"
            :props="props"
            :column="col.name"
          >
            <slot :name="'column-' + col.name" :props="props" :row="props.row">
              {{ col.value }}
            </slot>

            <slot
              :name="'column-edit-' + col.name"
              :props="props"
              :row="props.row"
            >
            </slot>
          </q-td>
        </q-tr>
</template>

//Then I get the filtered rows by getting the displayed tr elements(each tr element has rowID attribute) :
  getHtmlRows(): HTMLTableRowElement[] {
      let htmlTable = this.getHtmlTable();
      let htmlRows: HTMLTableRowElement[] = Array.from(
        htmlTable.querySelectorAll("tr.row-data")
      );

      return htmlRows;
    }, 
//If I want to get the row data corresponding to html row (tr) I used :
   getRowData(id: number): any {
      let table = this.$refs.qtableRef as QTable;
      let rowData = table.rows?.find((rw) => rw.id == id);
      return rowData;
    },

    getRowDataByHtmlRow(htmlRow: HTMLTableRowElement): any {
      let rowID = htmlRow.getAttribute("rowID");
      return this.getRowData(Number(rowID));
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an undocumented way of accessing the `computedRows` and `computedRowsNumber` properties that I only found after extensive Google searching...

1. Give your table a **ref**: `<q-table ref="table" />`
2. Access these properties via the ref:

   - `this.$refs.table.computedRows`
   - `this.$refs.table.computedRowsNumber`

This was added in [v2.0.0-**beta.9**](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/quasar-v2.0.0-beta.9) <sub>(March 8, 2021)</sub>

###### Explanation

`computedRows` -- gives you the displayed rows on *current* page

- Example: if there are 30 results in total, but only 10 are shown in the current page, this will only return those 10 rows -- want them all? see *filteredSortedRows*

`filteredSortedRows` -- gives you *ALL* the displayed rows across *all* pages

- Example: if there are 50 rows in total, but 30 rows match the filtered text and show up, and 10 rows are shown per page, this will return *ALL* those filtered 30 rows. If there's no filtered text, then this will return all those original 50 rows

`computedRowsNumber` -- gives you the length for the *total* displayed rows across *all* pages

- <sup>*same as `filteredSortedRows.length`*</sup>

When server-side data fetching is enabled the properties above may behave differently. I had to check the source code to discover that, but haven't tested this in practice.

[Source](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/quasar-v2.0.0-beta.9) | [Where I found it](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/14013)